# Line wrapping issues in bash/php

Tags: bash, xterm, prompt

I am writing a program that prints colored lines, and the more I do with it the more I find myself working around line wrapping issues that come up.

It is a sort of terminal written in php, here is the prompt:

```
$return = readline("\033[44m\033[1;37m{$this->text}>>\033[0m ");
```

If I scroll through history my text gets off by 10 characters, and if I type in 21 characters and delete one, it clears the whole line and begins deleting characters from the line above. This is on a console that is 47 columns wide

If I try to add escapes

```
$return = readline("\[\033[44m\033[1;37m\]{$this->text}>>\[\033[0m\] ");
```

then it prints the brackets...even if I add double backslashes.

```
\[\][timer]>>\[\]
```

I find the same thing for `echo -e`, I am really not sure what's going on.

Lastly, if I modify PS1 it works just fine.

```
[mike@crest ~]$ export PS1="\[\033[44m\033[1;37m\][timer]>>\[\033[0m\] "
[timer]>>
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

According to http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/053 the `checkwinsize` option may be necessary if scrolling through the command history:

```
shopt -s checkwinsize
```